# I need to update checkbox (checked or unchecked) from UI

Tags: apex, visualforce

If I check a checkbox from UI in database its value should change accordingly
what I have tried till now is below

```
public class CheckboxFunctionality 
{
    public List<Account> accList{get;set;}
    public String recordId{get;set;}
    public String nam{get;set;}
    public CheckboxFunctionality()
    {
        accList = new List<Account>();
        accList = [Select id, name, phone, isActive__c  From Account Order By LastModifiedDate DESC Limit 5];
    }

    public PageReference checkActive()
    {
        system.debug('------------'+recordId);
        system.debug('------------'+nam);
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.name = nam;
        acc.id = recordId;
        insert acc;
        system.debug('active = '+acc.isActive__c);
     //   insert acc;
        if(acc.isActive__c == true)
            acc.isActive__c = false;
        else if(acc.isActive__c == false)
            acc.isActive__c = true;
        update acc;
        system.debug('active 2= '+acc.isActive__c);
        return null;
    }
}

<apex:page controller="CheckboxFunctionality">
    <script src="/soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="callAF" action="{!checkActive}" reRender="pbt">
            <apex:param name="checkId" id="accId" value="" assignTo="{!recordId}"/>
            <apex:param name="accNam" id="accN" value="" assignTo="{!nam}"/>
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accList}" var="row" id="pbt">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:inputField value="{!row.isActive__c}" onclick="check('{!row.Id}','{!row.name}')"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{!row.name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!row.Phone}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        sforce.connection.sessionId='{!getSessionId()}';
        function check(recId, nam)
        {
        /*    var acc = new sforce.SObject("Account");
            acc.Id = recId;
         //   var create = sforce.connection.create([acc]);
         //   alert(create);
            alert(acc.isActive__c);
            if(acc.isActive__c == false)
                acc.isActive__c = true;
            else 
                acc.isActive__c = false;
        //    var create= sforce.connection.create([acc]); */
            callAF(recId, nam);
            alert('122345');
        }
    </script>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not giving correct value to checkbox as. So you need to update your code as

```
<apex:inputField value="{!row.isActive__c}" onclick="check('{!row.Id}','{!row.name}', this)" />
```

and then in your method

```
function check(recId, nam,checkBo)
{
   /*    var acc = new sforce.SObject("Account");
    acc.Id = recId;
    acc.checked = checkbo.checked
    //    var create= sforce.connection.create([acc]); */
    callAF(recId, nam,checkbo.checked);
    alert('122345');
 }
</script>
```

and in your actionfunction

```
<apex:actionFunction name="callAF" action="{!checkActive}" reRender="pbt">
            <apex:param name="checkId" id="accId" value="" assignTo="{!recordId}"/>
            <apex:param name="accNam" id="accN" value="" assignTo="{!nam}"/>
            <apex:param name="accAct" id="acat" value="" assignTo="{!ative}"/>
        </apex:actionFunction>
```

and in your controller declare a new public string ative and in your method

```
Account acc = new Account();
        acc.name = nam;
        acc.id = recordId;
acc.active__c = boolean.valueOf(ative)
        update acc; //use update because you are passing id
```

this will give you correct value or simple just update `acclist` but it will change last modified date for all records in the list. but you can update multiple records in bulk